# apache 2.4 with php on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, php5, apt, apache-2.4

I've just compiled and installed apache 2.4 on my debian squeeze machine. It was the first time I've compiled it on my own. My next step should be installing mod_php for the server. Now I was thinking if I MUST compile php on my own with all the related stuff like imap, mysql etc. or if I can install the php stuff via apt and just copy the related files into my apache2/modules folder. Can somehow give me a little hint on this procecdure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the CGI version of PHP, then you would not need to re-compile. Since you want to use mod_php you need re-compile PHP, and PHP modules, any other Apache modules, and basically anything that links into Apache/PHP.

Comment: ok thanks :) so I will consider if this will be worth all the work^^